# Google FooBar Code Running in IDE but failing all test cases

Tags: java

The problem I'm trying to solve is ‘Hey! I already did that.’
The problem statement is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907902/google-foobar-challenge-level-2-hey-i-already-did-that) but that isn't really my problem, as I've already created a solution that works for me on my IDE.

When I create a sample main to run the file in my IDE, I'm able to return the correct values for both test cases. However, when I verify it in foobar, I fail all test cases, including the two known cases.

I tried returning just 1, since that's the answer to the second test case, and that's able to past three of the test cases. However, when I run my code but put return 1; in the first line (rendering all of my code useless), I still fail all test cases. That means, for some reason, even when it doesn't get to my code, I'm failing all the test cases. However, Google isn't telling me anything about a compile error - it just says I'm failing the test cases.

Here's the code:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int solution(String n, int b) {
        int tick = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[1000000000];
        int ans = 0;
        while (true) {
            tick++;
            if (arr[Integer.parseInt(n)] == 0) {
                arr[Integer.parseInt(n)] = tick;
            } else {
                ans = tick - arr[Integer.parseInt(n)];
                //System.out.println(ans);
                return ans;
            }
            char[] ar;
            ar = n.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(ar);
            String i = String.valueOf(ar);
            String j = "";
            for (int a = (ar.length - 1); a >= 0; a--) {
                j += String.valueOf(ar[a]);
            }
            //System.out.println(i + " " + j);

            int x = Integer.valueOf(j);
            int y = Integer.valueOf(i);

            String a1 = Integer.toString(x);
            String b1 = Integer.toString(y);
            int p = 1;
            int xx = 0;
            int yy = 0;

            p = 0;
            for (int ii = a1.length() - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
                xx += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(a1.charAt(ii))) * Math.pow(b, p);
                p++;
            }

            p = 0;
            for (int ii = b1.length() - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
                yy += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(b1.charAt(ii))) * Math.pow(b, p);
                p++;
            }


            String zz = String.valueOf(xx - yy);

            String newn = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(zz), b);

            for (int ii = 0; ii < n.length() - newn.length(); ii++)
                newn = "0" + newn;
            n = newn;
            //System.out.println(n);
            //f = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, which was twofold - firstly, I was getting the error because, although foobar doesn't want wildcard imports, they do want specific imports (in this case, java.util.Arrays). However, when I did do that, it was still inefficient, so I changed it to a simple HashMap solution and I'm able to pass all test cases that way.